# in Angular, passing a value from resolve to the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I am trying to pass this variable to the controller and then display on the screen. I am not sure why I am getting undefined for that value. I went tru the  similar SO questions and it seems iam doing it right.

```
.state({
                name: "test",
                url: "/testURL",
                views: {
                    'testView': {
                        template: '<div><span>{{testvariable}} </span></div>',
                        controller: "testController",
                        resolve: {
                            testString: function () {
                                debugger;
                                return 'from Resolve';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            })
      })

      app.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$state",

        function ($scope, $state, testString) {
            console.log("getting from resolve ", testString)
            $scope.testvariable = function () {
                console.log("getting from resolve ", testString)
                return testString;
            }
            $scope.testvariable();

        }
      ])
```

Comment: because you didn't add it to the named dependencies: `["$scope", "$state", "testString", function (...)`

Comment: thanks but no thats not the issue. still does not work. iam not sure iam supposed to add it as a dependency actually. but tried, and gave a `angular.min.js:92 Error: [$injector:unpr]` error   which is  `Unknown provider: testStringProvider <- testString`

Comment: Try to put the `resolve` **outside** the `views` object (And also do what devqon wrote in the first comment)

Comment: ok both changes made it work! thanks to both of you :)

Comment: @AlonEitan question, the value is not displaying on the screen -  any idea?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel By "on screen", you mean the console? You should see `"getting from resolve ", 'from Resolve'` in the console

Comment: @AlonEitan yes sure, but i  meant i also have as a template, a div with a span which is supposed to print the variable. and its not printing. i have `<div ui-view="testView"></div>` in my index.html

Comment: So try to add `$scope.testString = testString;` on the first line of the controller, and in the view try to print it using `{{ testString }}` anywhere in the view (Or as an alternative: `<div ng-bind="testString"></div>` which is practically the same as `{{ testString }}` but more clean and recommended)

Comment: yes that worked!. thnks